# How to set a value base on the date as the Final day of the month in a new column

Tags: sql-server

I have the following script which pulls data from 2 different tables based on the date and sums the sales for the that Oracle number and groups it by Cust.ID. However, I want to include a new column that will only Sum the sales of the month and format it as The end of the month date.
So pretty much a new column that will group it by End of the month.
It might sound confusing but something like--- if the date falls between January 1 and January 30 then have a new column that formats it as 01-31-2015; if day fall between Feb 1st and Feb 28 then format it as 02-28-2015......and so on till 05-31-2016. By having this, I can have the sales for each month instead of throughout the year.

[image]

Comment: Google 'sql server end of month'

Comment: MySQL is not SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

If 2012+ you could try

```
EOMonth(datefield)
```